# Python xpath replace for loop with one line of xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am extracting the text from 10 div elements that aren't consistent. There are three possibilities: sometimes the text is in the `div` element, sometimes it is in the `a` element child of the `div` and sometimes the text in the `a` element has a `b` element that separates track name from remixer.

Right now my best solution includes sub-selecting all of the track elements (`div class="track"`) with xpath and then for each element/s get all the text and join into one string if the result has more than one element. 
Here's the example page [link](https://www.residentadvisor.net/dj/djt/top10?chart=135778).
The list with the `div`s is the result from:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="track"]').extract()

['<div class="track"><a href="/tracks/548559">Magic Bazar</a></div>',
'<div class="track"><a href="/tracks/546388">Diesel</a></div>',
'<div class="track"><a href="/tracks/555897">Something Strange<br>(Filsonik remix)</a></div>',
'<div class="track"><a href="/tracks/545940">Basik Fire</a></div>',
'<div class="track">Think Twice<br>(Catz \'n Dogz)</div>',
'<div class="track">The Mothership</div>',
'<div class="track">Addiction feat. Mizbee</div>',
'<div class="track"><a href="/tracks/543113">Stash</a></div>',
'<div class="track"><a href="/tracks/555900">Voyeur Feat. Thomas Gandey<br>(Alex Niggemann)</a></div>',
'<div class="track"><a href="/tracks/484505">Remember Me</a></div>']
```

Then I can do this:

```
for el in response.xpath('//div[@class="track"]'):
        track_and_remix = el.xpath('descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()
        track = "".join(track_and_remix)
```

Which gives me the desired result:

```
Magic Bazar
Diesel
Something Strange(Filsonik remix)
Basik Fire
Think Twice(Catz 'n Dogz)
The Mothership
Addiction feat. Mizbee
Stash
Voyeur Feat. Thomas Gandey(Alex Niggemann)
Remember Me
```

However I think that there's a more efficient way to get the same result. I think that one Xpath expression can be used to get the desired result. I would like the answer to use Scrapy's `ItemLoader` and get the data with one line of xpath expression.

The solution should result in a list of 10 elements in the correct order. I know of a one line solution that returns the remixers (items in brakets) as separate elements resulting in 13 element list.

Comment: Can you share how you are using `ItemLoader`? I don't know of one XPath 1.0 expression to get a list of text content for some selected nodes. I can see a one-XPath expression to call on each node, namely `string()` or `normalize-space()`, that would get you what you want for each track.

Comment: I am not yet using `ItemLoader`, I want to use it for a cleaner implementation.